# i am trying to use the avg() function in a subquery after using a count in the inner query but i cannot seem to get it work in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

my table name is `CustomerDetails` and it has the following columns:

```
customer_id, login_id, session_id, login_date
```

i am trying to write a query that calculates the average number of customers login in per day.

i tried this:

```
select avg(session_id)
from CustomerDetails
where exists (select count(session_id) from CustomerDetails as 'no_of_entries')
```

.

but then i realized it was going straight to the column and just calculating the average of that column but that's not what i want to do. can someone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is get logins per day:

```
SELECT login_date, COUNT(*) AS loginsPerDay
FROM CustomerDetails
GROUP BY login_date
```

Then you can use that to get average logins per day:

```
SELECT AVG(loginsPerDay)
FROM (
  SELECT login_date, COUNT(*) AS loginsPerDay
  FROM CustomerDetails
  GROUP BY login_date
)
```

If your login_date is a `DATE` type you're all set. If it has a time component then you'll need to truncate it to date only:

```
SELECT AVG(loginsPerDay)
FROM (
  SELECT CAST(login_date AS DATE), COUNT(*)
  FROM CustomerDetails
  GROUP BY CAST(login_date AS DATE)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. now i want to go further and pull up average users per day for last 5 days.. but i have gotten lost

Comment: Try adding `WHERE CAST(login_date AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY, -5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))` after the `FROM` and before the `GROUP BY` :)

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to write a query that calculates the average number of customers login in per day.

Count the number of customers.  Divide by the number of days.  I think that is:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct cast(login_date as date))
from customerdetails;
```

Comment: okay that seems to work , so i have to count all the customers and add 'distinct' to prevent repetition of customers or the date?? also what if i wanted to calculate for last 5 days? also can i use the avg function in anyway?

Comment: @Billz . . . Your question is unclear on whether you want distinct customers or rows.  You can use `count(distinct customerid)` if that is what you want.  For a range, you would add a `where` clause with the range you intend.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want do count the number of visitors per day, not the number of visits. So if a customer logged twice on the same day, you want to count him only once.

If so, you can use `distinct` and two levels of aggregation, like so:

```
select avg(cnt_visitors) avg_cnt_vistors_per_day
from (
    select count(distinct customer_id) cnt_visitors
    from customer_details 
    group by cast(login_date as date)
) t
```

The inner query computes the count of distinct customers for each day, he outer query gives you the overall average.

Comment: okay this is wonderful.. it works.. i have however added another outer query to calculate for last five days like so : select * datediff(day,login_date,getdate()) as 'period' from customer_details where datediff(day,login_date,getdate()) between 1 and 5.. however i am having difficulty adding this to the existing query

Comment: @Billz: to filter on the last 5 days, just add a `where` clause to the inner query, like: `from customer_details where login_date > cast(dateadd(day, -5, getdate()) as date)`